# Pagination gets background of deleted post

Tags: bug, user-interface, deleted-answers, pagination

I think there is a small UI bug, which seems to affect at least beta metas (likely beta mains, too, I don't know about graduated sites with their custom designs). When a deleted post is at the top of the page, the dark background of the deleted question extends into the pagination:

[image]

For those with enough rep on Code Golf (or SE staff), you can see it in action [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?page=31&tab=votes#tab-top).

**Edit:** Even for non-deleted questions it's a bit weird that the pagination is part of the answer's div. E.g. when you open a question with a link to the answer at the top of the page, and the answer is highlighted for a second, the highlighting also includes the pagination.

Comment: With the new beta design [this is no longer a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251472/201409) but I don't know if it still applies to some graduated sites. If it doesn't, feel free to close it.