# Pagination too close to deleted answers

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, deleted-answers, pagination

With the new beta design, while the spacing between the pagination and a normal answer's title looks really nice, it looks very crammed if the answer at the top is deleted:

[image]

I don't know if this affects other sites, but the designs (beta or not) seem to be fairly consistent, so I think this might be a network-wide issue. (If it's actually an issue.)

This probably supersedes [this bug report from last week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251173/201409) but I don't know if the old problem doesn't still exist on some graduated sites.